# How to close all open panels when another one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've got a search box running here:

http://codepen.io/h0rhay/pen/Kgqwt

Code:

```
$('.findNavL1').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.slideContainer').toggleClass('show').css('z-index', +1);
});

$('.slideContainer').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns width33">
        <div class="navContainer rel">
             <h2 class="navHeading">Find a holiday</h2>
             <ul class="findHolNav">
                <li class="findNavL1" onClick="return true"> <span>When</span>
                    <div class="slideContainer">
                         <h2 class="internalContent">This is some content 1</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="findNavL1" onClick="return true"> <span>How many Days </span>
                    <div class="slideContainer">
                         <h2 class="internalContent">This is some content 2</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="findNavL1" onClick="return true"> <span>Where</span>
                    <div class="slideContainer">
                         <h2 class="internalContent">This is some content 3</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="findNavL1" onClick="return true"> <span>Departing</span>
                    <div class="slideContainer">
                         <h2 class="internalContent">This is some content 4</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="findNavL1" onClick="return true"> <span>No. of People</span>
                    <div class="slideContainer">
                         <h2 class="internalContent">This is some content 5</h2>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.rel {
    position:relative;
}

.staticP {
    position:static !important;
}

.show {
    display:block !important;
}

.hide {
    display:none;
}

/* -----------------------------------------
   Shared Styles
----------------------------------------- */

.width33 {
    width:33.3% !important;
}

.navContainer {
    background:#ccc;
}

.findHolNav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
}

.findNavL1{
    cursor:pointer;

}

.findNavL1 span {
    padding:20px;
    display:block;
}

.findNavL1:nth-of-type(odd){
    background-color:#c6c6c6;
}

.findNavL1:hover{
    background-color:#c2c2c2;
}

.findNavL1:hover > .slideContainer, .findNavL1:active > .slideContainer {

}

.slideContainer {
    display:none;
    background-color:lime;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    width:208%;
}
```

At the moment, the UI is nearly right. When you click on a link the corresponding panel opens up.

However if you click on another link, its corresponding panel opens but the previous one stays open.

I want it to close.

Which would leave only the active one open.

//////////////////////////////////////

I should have said.. The UI is a bit more complex than maybe I said before.

1st click: Slides open the container.

Click same link: Slides shut

Click inside open container: Container remains open.

(I've got all this working ok)

If you click different link, then open container shuts and new one opens..

Thats the bit I'm stuck on.

Comment: put your code at http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can understand.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi codepen is just another jsfiddle (clone)

Comment: Why do you have click handlers both in code and in markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Got there in the end:

```
$('.findNavL1').click(function(){
var searchBoxLink = $(this);
var inactiveLink = $('.findNavL1').not(searchBoxLink);

if ( $(inactiveLink).children('.slideContainer').hasClass('show') ){
  $(inactiveLink).children('.slideContainer').removeClass('show');
}

$(searchBoxLink).children('.slideContainer').toggleClass('show');
});


$('.slideContainer').click(function(){
if ( $(this).hasClass('show') ){
 $(this).toggleClass('show');
        }
});
```

http://codepen.io/h0rhay/pen/Kgqwt

Answer (score 2):

Use the following JS instead of the one, which you have written ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwplz)):

```
$('.findNavL1').click(function(){
  $('.slideContainer').hide();
  $(this).find('.slideContainer').show();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it doesn't get the container to close when the link that opened it was clicked though

Answer (score 0):

change your block as below :

```
if ($(this).hasClass('show')){
    $(".slideContainer").removeClass("show");
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following...

```
$('.findNavL1').click(function(){
    $('.slideContainer').each(function( index ){
        $(this).removeClass('show');
        $(this).addClass('hide');
    });
    $(this).children('.slideContainer').addClass('show');
});
```

See this js fiddle...[example](http://jsfiddle.net/y76Tx/)

Comment: thanks, but same again, it doesn't close the container when you click on the same link that opened it..